# Why is “puppy” a cuss word in korean?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I know that a translation of the word “puppy” can be an insult/cuss word, but does anyone know why exactly?

Comment: Well, as for "why", consider that a puppy is *literally* a son or daughter of a bitch...

Comment: Hi - note that as per [this meta question](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/questions-about-offensive-language-should-they-be-allowed-and-should-we-take), we don't have to be coy about actually quoting offensive language, as long as it's a necessary part of a genuine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is “puppy” a cuss word in korean?

The most common translation of 'puppy', 강아지 , isn't commonly used as an insult.

> a translation of the word “puppy” can be an insult/cuss word.

I guess the particular translation you mean is 개새끼 - more literally "offspring of a dog" - offensive for much the same reasons as "son of a bitch" in English, as per jick's comment.